# How add Name to Route in Angular 13 as like Vue

Tags: angularjs

Right now I would like now how to set the name of a route in angular like Vue as I don't want to get the "path" but the alias, the same way as can be done in vue.

This is my app-routing.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LanguagesComponent } from './languages/languages.component';
const routes : Routes = [
  {path : 'login',component:LoginComponent},
  {path : 'languages',component:LanguagesComponent, name:"languages.index"}, //Set the name to route as can be done in vue
  {path : 'unauthorized',component:UnauthorizedComponent}
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Then I want to get the route name since a service in angular.
This is my sevice File:

```js
import { LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PermissionByRoleService  {

  constructor(public router: Router,private location: LocationStrategy){}

  get permissionByRole(): boolean {
    if(this.getCurrentRouteName()=="languages.index"){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }


  getCurrentRouteName(){
    console.log(this.location.path() ); //Get '/languages'
    console.log(this.router.url ); // I'm supposed to get '/languages' but I get '/'
    console.log();// How get route name something Similar To Vue
    return this.router.url ; // I neeed return route name according to porpierties of routes
  }
}
```

Would it be possible to do this?

If so.

How can I do this?

I appreciate any help